# .NET 8 Blazor Web App - How to access RouteData from MainLayout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

My layout needs to render differently based on the information in the route, for example if the url is https://localhost/{customerid}/{projectid}/dashboard

I need to be able to access the RouteData dictionary and get the customerid and projectid values.

Making routeData a cascading parameter value in the Layout does not seem to work as it always returns null.

How can I access the current routeData from a Layout?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example. Can you show a mocked up pair of routes and their layout needs.

Comment: Are you running a Blazor Server or WebAssembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get the `RouteData` is to cacade it from `Routes`.

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
         @* At this point routeData is a local field in the Routes component. *@
        <CascadingValue Value="routeData" >
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
</Router>
```

You can then access it in MainLayout:

```cs
    [CascadingParameter] private RouteData? routeData { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `NavigationManager` to access the url in `MainLayout.razor`. And if you need to have a button which clicking to get the URL and do something else, not only add the click event handler, but also change the `<Routes />` to `<Routes @rendermode=@RenderMode.InteractiveServer />` in `App.razor`.

My test is based on blazor web app ssr.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="top-row px-4">
    <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">About</a>
    <button @onclick="getUrl">get url</button>
</div>

@code {
    string CurrUrl = null;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        CurrUrl = NavigationManager.Uri.ToString();
    }

    private void getUrl()
    {
        CurrUrl = NavigationManager.Uri.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]